# Pandas How to filter a Series

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Series like this after doing groupby('name') and used mean() function on other column

```
name
383      3.000000
663      1.000000
726      1.000000
737      9.000000
833      8.166667
```

Could anyone please show me how to filter out the rows with 1.000000 mean values? Thank you and I greatly appreciate your help.

Comment: Well, how would you filter a series upon a given condition?

Answer (score 198, accepted):

```
In [5]:

import pandas as pd

test = {
383:    3.000000,
663:    1.000000,
726:    1.000000,
737:    9.000000,
833:    8.166667
}

s = pd.Series(test)
s = s[s != 1]
s
Out[0]:
383    3.000000
737    9.000000
833    8.166667
dtype: float64
```

Comment: I prefer the answers below because they can be chained (i.e. no need to define `s` and then use it twice in the expression). Only works from pandas 0.18 though.

Comment: Also see timing comparisons in piRSquared's [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43401268/5276797).

Answer (score 106):

From pandas version 0.18+ filtering a series can also be done as below

```
test = {
383:    3.000000,
663:    1.000000,
726:    1.000000,
737:    9.000000,
833:    8.166667
}

pd.Series(test).where(lambda x : x!=1).dropna()
```

Checkout:
http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.18.1/whatsnew.html#method-chaininng-improvements

Comment: So much nicer with method chaining (and reminds me of Spark.)

Comment: True but Spark does something more intuitive in this case: it simply gets rid of rows that don't match the predicate, that means not using the ".dropna()" part which seemed clearly superfluous to me until I read the doc. Got bitten by that :D

Answer (score 83):

As [DACW pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37327506/1175496), there are [method-chaining improvements](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.18.1/whatsnew.html#method-chaininng-improvements) in pandas 0.18.1 that do what you are looking for very nicely.

Rather than using `.where`, you can pass your function to either the `.loc` indexer or the Series indexer `[]` and avoid the call to `.dropna`:

```
test = pd.Series({
383:    3.000000,
663:    1.000000,
726:    1.000000,
737:    9.000000,
833:    8.166667
})

test.loc[lambda x : x!=1]

test[lambda x: x!=1]
```

Similar behavior is supported on the DataFrame and NDFrame classes.

Comment: This is my favorite answer, and it also seems to be the fastest without going down to numpy (see timing comparisons).

Answer (score 32):

A fast way of doing this is to reconstruct using `numpy` to slice the underlying arrays.  See timings below.

```
mask = s.values != 1
pd.Series(s.values[mask], s.index[mask])

0
383    3.000000
737    9.000000
833    8.166667
dtype: float64
```

***naive timing***

[image]

Comment: ，I like your method, I wanna know what if I have multi-masks. Thx

Comment: @MenglongLi depends, you should ask a question. Most likely, you'd combine them with &. mask = mask1 & mask2

Answer (score 7):

Another way is to first convert to a DataFrame and use the [query](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) method (assuming you have numexpr installed):

```
import pandas as pd

test = {
383:    3.000000,
663:    1.000000,
726:    1.000000,
737:    9.000000,
833:    8.166667
}

s = pd.Series(test)
s.to_frame(name='x').query("x != 1")
```

Comment: I don't think that it's a good idea to pass a condition as a string

Comment: This adds all the overhead of a dataframe, and is going to be very slow.

Answer (score 4):

If you like a chained operation, you can also use `compress` function:

```
test = pd.Series({
383:    3.000000,
663:    1.000000,
726:    1.000000,
737:    9.000000,
833:    8.166667
})

test.compress(lambda x: x != 1)

# 383    3.000000
# 737    9.000000
# 833    8.166667
# dtype: float64
```

Comment: Please note `pandas.Series.compress` is deprecated since version 0.24.0. of `pandas`.

Answer (score 2):

In my case I had a *pandas Series where the values are tuples of characters*:

```
Out[67]
0    (H, H, H, H)
1    (H, H, H, T)
2    (H, H, T, H)
3    (H, H, T, T)
4    (H, T, H, H)
```

Therefore I could use indexing to filter the series, but to create the index I needed `apply`. My condition is "find all tuples which have exactly one 'H'".

```
series_of_tuples[series_of_tuples.apply(lambda x: x.count('H')==1)]
```

I admit it is *not "chainable"*, (i.e. notice I repeat `series_of_tuples` twice; you must store any temporary series into a variable so you can call apply(...) on it).

There may also be *other methods* (besides `.apply(...)`)  which can *operate elementwise to produce a Boolean index.*

Many other answers (including accepted answer) using the chainable functions like:

- `.compress()`
- `.where()`
- `.loc[]`
- `[]`

These accept callables (lambdas) **which are applied to the Series**, not to the individual *values* in those series!

Therefore my Series of tuples behaved strangely when I tried to use my above condition / callable / lambda, with any of the chainable functions, like `.loc[]`:

```
series_of_tuples.loc[lambda x: x.count('H')==1]
```

Produces the error:

KeyError: 'Level H must be same as name (None)'

I was very confused, but it seems to be using the [Series.count `series_of_tuples.count(...)` function](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.count.html#pandas.Series.count) , which is not what I wanted.

I admit that an alternative data structure may be better:

- A Category datatype?
- A Dataframe (each element of the tuple becomes a column)
- A Series of strings (just concatenate the tuples together):

This creates a series of strings (i.e. by concatenating the tuple; joining the characters in the tuple on a single string)

```
series_of_tuples.apply(''.join)
```

So I can then use the [chainable `Series.str.count`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.count.html#pandas.Series.str.count)

```
series_of_tuples.apply(''.join).str.count('H')==1
```