# Filtering a pandas series using a lambda expression that operates on individual elements

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, series

I'm trying to using pandas for chaining together map and filter operations.
I've come across several options, partly outlined in here: 
[Pandas How to filter a Series](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28272137/pandas-how-to-filter-a-series)

To summarize,

```
s = Series(range(10))

s.where(s > 4).dropna()
s.where(lambda x: x > 4).dropna()

s.loc[s > 4]
s.loc[lambda x: x > 4]

s.to_frame(name='x').query("x > 4")
```

This is fine for numerical comparisons and equality checks, but it doesn't work for predicates involving other operations. 
For a simple example, consider matching against the first character of a string.

```
s = Series(['aa', 'ab', 'ba'])
s.loc[lambda x: x.startswith('a')] # fails
```

This fails with a message like "Series has no attribute 'startswith'" since the argument `x` passed to the lambda expression in the second line is the series itself, rather than the individual elements it contains.

Interestingly `map` does allow element-wise access:

```
Series(list('abcd')).map(lambda x: x.upper())
# results in ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'] even though Series has no upper method
```

While there's probably some clever ways to handle the `startswith` example, I'm hoping to find a more general solution where a series can be filtered using a function that accepts individual values from the collection. And ideally it would allow chaining together operations as in,

```
s = (Series(...)
        .map(...)
        .where(...)
        .map(...))
```

Is that supported in pandas?

UPDATE:
Scott provided the answer for cases where the value is a string, which can be handled with `Series.str` as described in his answer.

But what about cases with a Series containing objects? 
Is there any way to access their attributes or apply functions to them?

I guess a standard way of managing that case would be to de-structure the the relevant fields of the object into a data frame, where each attribute is a column. Though there might be cases where someone would want to transform a collection of objects with map and filter(loc/where), without having to disassemble the complex type into a dataframe then immediately convert back.

I'm partly trying to find an alternative to the standard map()/filter() functions in python, where the operations have to be nested in reverse.

Ie,

```
map(function3, filter(function2, map(function1, collection)))
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the `.str` the string accessor needed for Pandas series and string operations.

```
s = Series(['aa', 'ab', 'ba'])
s.loc[lambda x: x.str.startswith('a')]
```

When you are using map, you are apply the string function to each element therefore you don't need the string accessor.

And to @piRSquared's point in the comments, you don't need lambda at all, you can use boolean indexing.

```
s = pd.Series(['aa', 'ab', 'ba']) 
s.loc[s.str.startswith('a')]
```

`s.str.startswith` returns a True False boolean series which when placed in backets for a series returns only those values that align with True.

Comment: Thanks. That's just what I was looking for to handle the string case. Though I'm wondering if there's a similar feature for handling the a Series of arbitrary objects. (I updated my question above to explain)

Comment: Yes, you can you map and apply custom functions to your series.

Comment: Is there any way to filter with (loc/where/query)? It throws an error every time I try. Map and apply work though

Answer (score 0):

```
s = Series(['aa', 'ab', 'ba'])
s.loc[lambda x: x.startswith('a')] # fails
```

This fails because `.loc[]` expects a Series/array of True/False values, which the supplied lambda function fails to provide. Easy solution to this, that works in the general case, is to first use `.map()` to apply the condition to each element, then supply the resulting boolean array to `.loc[]`. Like this:

```
s = Series(['aa', 'ab', 'ba'])
s.loc[s.map(lambda x: x.startswith('a'))]
```