# Syntax error with '!<' filtering pandas

Tags: python, linux, pandas, filter

I have a variable called 'Biovolumes_vivo' type float64. I want to filter and remove the values higher than 8192.

I've done some research and I found something similar here: [Pandas How to filter a Series](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28272137/pandas-how-to-filter-a-series)

I modified the script according to my data:

```
Biovolumes_vivo = Biovolumes_vivo[Biovolumes_vivo !< 8192]
```

However, it says 'invalid syntax'.

I guees there is something wrong with '!<'.
Thanks in advance for the help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`!<` is invalid you want

```
Biovolumes_vivo = Biovolumes_vivo[Biovolumes_vivo < 8192]
```

the valid operators here are `<`, `>`, `==`, `!=`, `<=`, `>=` for comparison there are also `pandas` equivalents such as:

```
Biovolumes_vivo = Biovolumes_vivo[Biovolumes_vivo.lt(8192)]
```

which is [`lt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.lt.html#pandas.DataFrame.lt) which means less than

Comment: Thank you very much! That helped :)

Answer (score 0):

```
Biovolumes_vivo = Biovolumes_vivo[Biovolumes_vivo !< 8192]
```

Is not a valid syntax. If you want to perform a conditional test that is lower than 8192 you would need to use the < operator. If !< means not lower than, you will want to use the > than operator instead. Here is an example:

```
Biovolumes_vivo = Biovolumes_vivo[Biovolumes_vivo > 8192]
```

As you know, this will return a df of the values that are true in pandas.