# Pandas filter a series

Tags: python, pandas

I saw [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28272137/pandas-how-to-filter-a-series) that this should work :

```
test = pd.Series({
383:    3.000000,
663:    1.000000,
726:    1.000000,
737:    9.000000,
833:    8.166667
})
test[lambda x: x!=1]
```

And i ran it and it did work, So i dont get why this wouldnt :

```
ex=pandas.Series({
383:    "Hello",
663:    "Hello",
726:    "Gallo",
737:    "Jello",
833:    "Gallo"
})
pprint(ex[lambda item : item.startswith("Hello")])
```

I get error :

> AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'startswith'

Any one can tell me whats going on, why is item parameter a Seria? why x!=1 seemed to work on the actual values in the seria while item.startswith doesnt?

Comment: use `ex[ex.str.startswith("Hello")]` instead.

Comment: use `str.startswith` instead of just `startswith` to access `pandas` string methods. But there is no need for a lambda in this situation