# How to filter a Pandas series?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, series

I want to filter a Pandas Series to remove certain values. This seems like such a simple task, but the preferred answer to the [same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28272137/pandas-how-to-filter-a-series) doesn't work for me.

Here's my reproducible example:

```
data = np.array([['','Col1','Col2'],
                ['Row1',1,2],
                ['Row2',3,4]])

myDF = pd.DataFrame(data=data[1:,1:],
                  index=data[1:,0],
                  columns=data[0,1:])

mySeries = myDF.loc[:, "Col1"]
mySeries[mySeries != 1]
```

I expect the final line to output a single row, containing the value 3, but instead I get:

```
Row1    1
Row2    3
Name: Col1, dtype: object
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the dtype of the NumPy array you are creating:

```
data = np.array([['','Col1','Col2'],
                 ['Row1',1,2],
                 ['Row2',3,4]])

print(data)

array([['', 'Col1', 'Col2'],
       ['Row1', '1', '2'],
       ['Row2', '3', '4']], 
      dtype='<U4')
```

Combining strings and integers in a nested list before feeding to `np.array` creates an array of strings, evidenced by `'<U4'`, which represents the maximum number of characters.

If you use lists instead, you won't meet this problem as the implementation ensures an array is created with appropriate types:

```
data = [['','Col1','Col2'],
        ['Row1',1,2],
        ['Row2',3,4]]

myDF = pd.DataFrame(data=[i[1:] for i in data[1:]],
                    index=[i[0] for i in data[1:]],
                    columns=data[0][1:])
```

Answer (score 3):

Your `Series` contains strings.

```
>>> mySeries.tolist()
>>> ['1', '3']
```

You can use

```
>>> mySeries[mySeries != '1']
>>> 
Row2    3
Name: Col1, dtype: object
```

This happens because `numpy` arrays hold a single data type, thus the integers are casted to strings when you create `data`.

If you want the integers, you can use

```
>>> mySeries = mySeries.astype(int)
>>> mySeries
>>> 
Row1    1
Row2    3
Name: Col1, dtype: int64
```

and your original code will work just fine.

Answer (score 2):

```
mySeries = mySeries.astype(int)
mySeries.loc[mySeries != 1]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
mySeries = pd.to_numeric(mySeries)
```

..that will fix it