# How can I get the indexes of a filtered Panda series?

Tags: python, pandas

I am working with 13548 continuous values, my data is constructed on the following way:

`s = pd.Series(delta, index=st)`
`s[:10]`

GEOM_190_190     0.00
GEOM_190_192     1.91
GEOM_190_194     2.54
GEOM_190_196     4.90
GEOM_190_198     6.03
GEOM_190_200     6.92
GEOM_190_202     8.60
GEOM_190_204    10.06
GEOM_190_206    11.34
GEOM_190_208    12.43
dtype: float64

I apply the following filters:
`extra = [i for i in s if i<52.55]`
`extra2 = [i for i in s if i>61 and i<68]`
`extra3 = [i for i in s if i>73]`

I would like to know the indexes of those values.
Is there a better way to do it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [loc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.loc.html) to access a group of rows and return another Series, which you can then use to inspect the index.

```
import pandas as pd

test = pd.Series({
    1: 5.0,
    2: 4.5,
    3: 8.2,
    4: 9.0,
    5: 6.7
})

extra = test.loc[lambda x: x < 8]
# or extra = test[test < 8] # more concise but potentially slower

print(extra)
# 1    5.0
# 2    4.5
# 5    6.7
# dtype: float64
```

There are a few ways to do this and the performance can differ as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43401268/10682164).

EDIT: to do multiple conditions in one `loc` try something like the following:

```
test.loc[(test > 5) & (test < 8)]
# 5    6.7
# dtype: float64
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, however I still cannot do it in the case of x between 61 and 68.