# Conduct the calculation only when the date value is valid

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame `dft`:

```
Date              Total Value
02/01/2022          2
03/01/2022          6 
N/A                 4
03/11/2022          4
03/15/2022          4
05/01/2022          4
```

For each date in the data frame, I want to calculate the how many days from today and I want to add these calculated values in a new column called `Days`.

I have tried the following code:

```
newdft = []
for item in dft:
  temp = item.copy()
  timediff = datetime.now() - datetime.strptime(temp["Date"], "%m/%d/%Y")
  temp["Days"] = timediff.days
  newdft.append(temp)
```

But the third date value is N/A, which caused an error. What should I add to my code so that I only conduct the calculation only when the date value is valid?

Comment: If you convert your Date column to a date time object, you can get do `datetime.now() - dft['Date']` and get the column in one go

Comment: Oh actually, reading a little closer, I'm not sure what your code is doing. Normally, `for item in df` iterates over the column labels, not the row values. So just in case the linked question doesn't work for you, you need to provide a [mre] including complete code, expected output, and the [full error message with traceback](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/359146/4518341). (See also [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](/q/20109391/4518341).)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would convert the whole Date column to be a date time object, using [`pd.to_datetime()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html), with the errors set to coerce, to replace the 'N/A' string to `NaT` (Not a Timestamp) with the below:

```
dft['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(dft['Date'], errors='coerce')
```

So the column will now look like this:

```
0   2022-02-01
1   2022-03-01
2          NaT
3   2022-03-11
4   2022-03-15
5   2022-05-01
Name: Date, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

You can then subtract that column from the current date in one go, which will automatically ignore the NaT value, and assign this as a new column:

```
dft['Days'] = datetime.now() - dft['Date']
```

This will make dft look like below:

```
        Date  Total Value                     Days
0 2022-02-01            2 148 days 15:49:03.406935
1 2022-03-01            6 120 days 15:49:03.406935
2        NaT            4                      NaT
3 2022-03-11            4 110 days 15:49:03.406935
4 2022-03-15            4 106 days 15:49:03.406935
5 2022-05-01            4  59 days 15:49:03.406935
```

If you just want the number instead of `59 days 15:49:03.406935`, you can do the below instead:

```
df['Days'] = (datetime.now() - df['Date']).dt.days
```

Which will give you:

```
        Date  Total Value   Days
0 2022-02-01            2  148.0
1 2022-03-01            6  120.0
2        NaT            4    NaN
3 2022-03-11            4  110.0
4 2022-03-15            4  106.0
5 2022-05-01            4   59.0
```

Comment: Another option to get just the days is `df['Days'] = date.today() - df['Date'].dt.date`, which is dtype `timedelta64[ns]`.

Comment: Thank you so much, but `dft['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(dft['Date'], errors='coerce')` will give me the error: "list indices must be integers or slices, not str" How do I fix this?

Comment: @Mary hmmmm, that's odd. Would you be able to provide me with the outputs of `dft.dtypes` and `dft['Dates'].to_list()`?

Comment: @EmiOB The output of `dft.dtypes` is 'list' object has no attribute 'dtypes'. The output of  `dft['Dates'].to_list()` is list indices must be integers or slices, not str. I think I know why. My dft is a list of dictionaries, not a data frame

Comment: ah ok, my answer assumes it's a dafaframe. You can easily turn it into one with pd.DataFrame(dft) and then it'll work

Answer (score 1):

Following up on the excellent answer by Emi OB I would suggest using `DataFrame.mask()` to update the dataframe without type coercion.

```py
import datetime
import pandas as pd

dft = pd.DataFrame({'Date': [
  '02/01/2022',
  '03/01/2022',
  None,
  '03/11/2022',
  '03/15/2022',
  '05/01/2022'],
  'Total Value': [2,6,4,4,4,4]})

dft['today'] = datetime.datetime.now()
dft['Days'] = 0
dft['Days'].mask(dft['Date'].notna(),
                 (dft['today'] - pd.to_datetime(dft['Date'])).dt.days,
                 axis=0, inplace=True)
dft.drop(columns=['today'], inplace=True)
```

This would result in integer values in the `Days` column:

```
         Date  Total Value  Days
0  02/01/2022            2   148
1  03/01/2022            6   120
2        None            4  None
3  03/11/2022            4   110
4  03/15/2022            4   106
5  05/01/2022            4    59
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with `DataFrame.mask()` (still pretty new to Pandas), but this doesn't seem to work. I get an error: `ValueError: Columns must be same length as key` at `dft['Days'] = dft.mask(...`. Is this something that might have changed between Pandas versions?

Comment: Is it supposed to be `dft.mask(...)['Days']`? But then you get `0` instead of `None` in the `Days` column.

Comment: @wjandrea Interesting, I could not reproduce your error, but in general your point is correct, that is the number of columns should be the same. I believe the best fix would be to use the `inplace=True` flag to avoid the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

In contrast to [Emi OB's excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72803445/4518341), if you did actually need to process individual values, it's usually easier to use `apply` to create a new Series from an existing one. You'd just need to [filter out](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28272137/4518341) `'N/A'`.

```
df['Days'] = (
    df['Date']
    [lambda d: d != 'N/A']
    .apply(lambda d: (datetime.now() - datetime.strptime(d, "%m/%d/%Y")).days)
    )
```

Result:

```
         Date  Total Value   Days
0  02/01/2022            2  148.0
1  03/01/2022            6  120.0
2         N/A            4    NaN
3  03/11/2022            4  110.0
4  03/15/2022            4  106.0
5  05/01/2022            4   59.0
```

---

And for what it's worth, another option is `date.today()` instead of `datetime.now()`:

```
    .apply(lambda d: date.today() - datetime.strptime(d, "%m/%d/%Y").date())
```

And the result is a timedelta instead of float:

```
         Date  Total Value      Days
0  02/01/2022            2  148 days
1  03/01/2022            6  120 days
2         N/A            4       NaT
3  03/11/2022            4  110 days
4  03/15/2022            4  106 days
5  05/01/2022            4   59 days
```

---

See also: [How do I select rows from a DataFrame based on column values?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17071871/4518341)